# Can we have multiple IF (3 to 5 conditions, if it start with 1z33 it's UPS if it start with 4455 it's fedex...) for one cell in Excel ? Pc Windows 11

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

Is it possible to have multiple IF for one Cell? example if leftA1 =4455,"Maro" if=5522, "John" and so on...
I work in shipping and when I scan a product shipping label I need it to show the courier company/
Thank you

Comment: For more info see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8

Comment: What do you get when you try it?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45 IFS function.

Answer (score 4):

You can nest `IF`s:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,4)="1z33","UPS",IF(LEFT(A1,4)="4455","fedex",...))
```

continue nesting them till you have exhausted the list.

You can also use `IFS` if you have it:

```
=IFS(LEFT(A1,4)="1z33","UPS",LEFT(A1,4)="4455","fedex",...)
```

You can also use NDEX/MATCH if it is always looking at the first four characters:

```
=INDEX({"UPS","fedex",...},MATCH(LEFT(A1,4),{"1z33","4455",...},0))
```

Comment: This is Great it worked Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use [`SWITCH()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e):

```
=SWITCH(LEFT(A1,4),"1z33","UPS","4455","FEDEX")
```

You can build out this formula with up to 126 options.